# Characterization or examples of metric spaces with this property

Tags: general-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $J$ be a subgroup of $\text{Isom}(X)$. For any $x \in X$ and compact subset $K \subset X$, consider the set
$$A = \left\{ g \in J : g(x) \in K \right\}.$$
What conditions on $X$ and/or J are necessary/sufficient in order to conclude that $A \subset \text{Isom}(X)$ is compact? (Here $\text{Isom}(X)$ carries the compact-open topology).

For example, I know $A$ is compact when $X = \mathbb{H}^2$ and $J = \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ or $J = \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Do you know the statement of Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: You need to first endow $\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ with a topology for the question to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples, I assume that you are mostly interested in **proper** metric spaces, i.e. metric spaces where a subset if compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. The most natural topology on the group of isometries $Isom(X)$ in this case is the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets. (Equivalently, you can equip $Isom(X)$ with topology of pointwise convergence.)

You probably also want to consider **closed subgroups** $J< Isom(X)$.

It is an application of Arzela-Ascoli theorem (combined with the diagonal argument) that in this setting the subset 
$$
A_{J,K,x} = \left\{ g \in J : g(x) \in K \right\}$$
is compact in $Isom(X)$ and, hence (since $J$ is closed), in $J$.